# React Native, Fetch specific data from API Results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-native

I am making an app using React Native to show railway PNR status after entering PNR Number using API.

API Results,

```
Array [
  Object {
    "data": Object {
      "boarding_station": Object {
        "day_count": "X",
        "departure_time": "XX:XX",
        "station_code": "XXX",
        "station_name": "XXXXX",
      },
      "booking_date": "XX/XX/XXXX",
      "chart_prepared": X,
      "class": "XX",
      "date": "XXXX-XX-XX",
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      "passenger": Array [
        Object {
          "bookingBerthCode": "XX",
          "bookingBerthNo": "XX",
          "bookingCoachId": "XX",
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        },
      ],
      "pnr_number": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
      "quota": "XX",
      "train_name": "XXXX",
      "train_number": "XXXX",
    },
    "message": "Success",
    "status": true,
    "timestamp": XXXXX,
  },
]
```

Code

```
const [apiResults, setAPIResults] = useState([])

const fetchPNRStatus = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`API Link`, headers)
            const results = await response.json()
            setAPIResults([results])
            console.log(apiResults)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message)
        }
    }
```

`console.log(apiResults)` displays the API results as given above. But I want to get specific values like `departure_time` under `boarding_station` array or `booking_date` or
`bookingBerthCode` under `passenger` array etc.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. Since, the api response is an array and there is only one object inside the array so all I needed was to use `apiResults[0]` to access that object.

So, for `departure_time` it will be `apiResults[0].data.boarding_station.departure_time`.

Similarly, for `booking_date`, `apiResults[0].data.booking_date`.
And, for `bookingBerthCode`, it is `apiResults[0].data.passenger[0].bookingBerthCode`.